# How to reformulate these expressions

Tags: expressions, reformulation

I am trying to explain to a responsible that my inscription on a website was not accpeted because the document I've uploaded was not conform. As a consequence, I made an appointment with that service in order to table a paper version of the document.

I tried the following:

> Bonjour, J'ai essayé d'inscrire sur le site ..... mais malheurement ma
>   candidature n'est pas été accepté parce que le document n'est pas
>   confome. Pour cela, j'ai pris un rendez-vous avec leur service pour
>   déposer la version papier du document.

Could you please help correct this email?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: and possibly explain to what the document was not conform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Bonjour, j'ai essayé **de m'**inscrire sur le site ....

the verb is : s'inscrire in this case.

> mais **malheureusement** ma candidature **n'a pas été acceptée** parce que le document n'est pas confo**r**me.

n'a pas été acceptée, because it is the passive form, constructed with avoir auxiliary

> J'ai pris un rendez-vous avec leur service pour déposer la version papier du document et ainsi valider mon inscription.

"Pour cela" seem weird here (can't really explain why :'( )

Comment: Afin de remplacer *Pour cela*, on pourrait aussi utiliser *Pour y remédier* ( un peu formel) ou *Pour régler ce problème*.

Comment: You can also use *Cependant* (However) in place of *Mais malheureusement* (less negative view), and drop the *un* in *J'ai pris __un__ rendez-vous*. If *Pour cela* seems weird, it's because it may imply a solution to a goal set in the previous sentence. In this paragraph, there's no goal: it is just said that the inscription was not successfull.